# How to export Variable when using runuser

Tags: r, linux, selinux, rscript

I am trying to run `Rscript` as a different user under constrained environment with a user which do not have the access to `/tmp`.

As the `Rscript` create a tmp file, it needs access to `/tmp`. So i thought if i can tell `Rscript` to change the tmp directory and user the one i specify.

In the documention it is mentioned that `Rscript` looks at the `$TMPDIR` environment variable to set its `tmp` directory

Below are all the failed trails to pass the environment variable.

```
ATTEMPT-1: runuser -l MYUSER -c "export TMPDIR=/SOME_DIR && echo $TMPDIR"
ATTEMPT-2: runuser -l MYUSER TMPDIR=/SOME_DIR -c "echo $TMPDIR"
ATTEMPT-3: runuser -l MYUSER TMPDIR=/SOME_DIR -c "echo $TMPDIR"
ATTEMPT-3: runuser -l MYUSER -c "Rscript --TMPDIR=/SOME_DIR test.r "   --> Random stuff
```

All attempt failed.

I cannot move away from `runuser` .

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried your examples but none of them could work because $TMPDIR is already replaced by the invoking shell. So, your

```
runuser -l MYUSER -c "export TMPDIR=/SOME_DIR && echo $TMPDIR"
```

becomes

```
runuser -l MYUSER -c "export TMPDIR=/SOME_DIR && echo "
```

if TMPDIR is empty or unset. Try with single quotes to avoid this:

```
 runuser -l MYUSER -c 'export TMPDIR=/SOME_DIR && echo $TMPDIR'
```

should result in the output `/SOME_DIR`.